# Why we can get offset of a struct like this?

Tags: c, struct, offset

Today I got some information that we can get the offset of a field in structure this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sdshdr {
    int len;
    int free;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", &sdshdr::len);
    printf("%d\n", &sdshdr::free);
}
```

Although I got warnings at compile time, it can successfully run.
How can we explain this? I didn't get information when I searched the web.
Can anyone help explain what happened here?

compilation arguments: `gcc -g -O2 -Wall -o main.o main.cpp`

Comment: With which compiler flags and which compiler are you building this program?

Comment: Nope, error: expected ')' before ':' token http://codepad.org/ZsNJY08g

Comment: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -o main.o main.cpp

Comment: sorry, I update the whole program and compiler flags in the text

Comment: It doesn't compile on my computer, `::` is a `C++` artifact, use `printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct sdshdr, len));`

Comment: @meeme The question makes sense if it refers to C (as it was initially formed). So I removed C++ tag and reset C tag.:)

Comment: Sorry, it compiles with warnings using `.cpp` as extension.

Answer (score 3):

Code you showed is not a C-compliant code. These constructions

`&sdshdr::len` and `&sdshdr::free` are not valid C constructions.

It seems you compiled the code as a C++ code.

If you want to know the offset of a data member of a structure in C then you should use standard macro `offsetof` declared in header `<stddef.h>`

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct sdshdr {
    int len;
    int free;
};


int main(void) 
{
    printf( "offset of len is equal to %zu\n", offsetof( struct sdshdr, len ) );    
    printf( "offset of free is equal to %zu\n", offsetof( struct sdshdr, free ) );  

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
offset of len is equal to 0
offset of free is equal to 4
```

If you mean C++ then these expressions

&sdshdr::len`and`&sdshdr::free` denote pointers to data members within the structure.

Comment: `It seems you compiled the code as a C++ code.`, compilation arguments: `gcc ...`, to compile as C++ code you need `g++ ...`, isn't it?

Comment: @Alter Mann I myself use MS VC++. :) But I see that the extension of the program is .cpp: main.cpp. So I am sure that the code is compiled as a C++ code.

Comment: Oooops, changed extension from .c to .cpp and it compiles with warnings, I didn't know that

Comment: @Alter: `gcc` will infer the language from the extension; in this case, it assumes `*.cpp` is a C++ file unless you explicitly tell it otherwise. (at least I assume it infers C++ from `*.cpp`. I know it will from `*.cc`)

Comment: @Alter Mann this is my first question at stackoverflow, seems my unclear description makes trouble to you, sorry about that. will be more careful next time.